# Unit testing react with jest 0.4.0 and node 0.12.0

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to write unit tests for a simple react component that has a radio button. Whether or not the test is failing is beside the point because I am getting syntax errors before the test can do its job.
I am running React0.14.7, node0.12.0, and jest 0.4.0 (this version of jest is compatible with node0.12.0. My dependencies are listed below.

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "^9.0.3",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.7.2",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"gulp": "latest",
"gulp-concat": "latest",
"gulp-less": "latest",
"gulp-react": "latest",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "latest",
"jest-cli": "^0.4.0",
"watch": "latest"
},
"jest": {
  "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
"testFileExtensions": ["es6", "js"],
"moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "es6"]
```

}

This is my test "../src/**tests**/radio-group-test.js"

```
jest.unmock('../components/radio-group.jsx')

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils'
import PolicyConditions from '../components/radio-group.jsx'

describe('../components/radio-group.jsx', () => {
  it('renders a subform when clicking a checkbox', () => {
    var conditions = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <RadioGroup 
        radioType='labelRadios'
        name='email'
      />
    )

    var radioNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(radio)

    expect(radioNode.checked).toEqual('false')

    TestUtils.Simulate.change(
      TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(radio, 'checked')
    )

    expect(radioNode.checked).toEqual('true')
  })
})
```

The error from the terminal:

```
SyntaxError: ../node_modules/babel-jest: ../node_modules/babel-jest/src/index.js:15
process(src, filename) {
       ^ 
Unexpected token (
```

Its almost as if babel isn't doing its job in translating es2015 because I had an earlier error with using `const` before changing it to `var`.

Edit: apologies, forgot to add the code that is actually failing.

```
'use strict';

var babel = require('babel-core');
var jestPreset = require('babel-preset-jest');

module.exports = {
  process(src, filename) {
    if (babel.util.canCompile(filename)) {
      return babel.transform(src, {
        auxiliaryCommentBefore: 'istanbul ignore next',
        filename,
        presets: [jestPreset],
        retainLines: true,
      }).code;
    }
    return src;
  },
};
```